# PHPUnit & Laravel testing bug?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, laravel-4, phpunit

I am having this weired error, I believe both PHPUnit and TestCase have setUp method and I am using the setUp method of TestCase rather than PHPUnit and still its saying it should be compatible with PHPUnit?
What is wrong with this?
[image: PHPUNIT]

[image: My MatchesControllerTest Class which extends TestCase (Laravel)]

Comment: On a screenshot php says `setUp()` is declared on line 85 which definitely isn't on your screenshot. How is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised myself, but there isn't anything there, just an end of class thats all!

Comment: is there a chance you've opened a wrong file?

Comment: No, this is the only file I've written and have.

Comment: What if you completely remove setUp and tearDown definitions?

Comment: Interesting, I am still getting error but the latter part of the first screen shot,
Call to member function format() ...